# #validate not overriding the submit function

Tags: forms

I'm creating a form in my own module (call it `mymodule`) and using a `#validate` property to clear the form. In my form definition, after calling hook_menu and hook_form,

```
function mymodule_myform($form_state){
$form['main']=array(
    '#type'=>'fieldset',
    '#title'=>t('Information'),
    '#collapsible'=>TRUE,
    '#collapsed'=>FALSE,
);
$form['main']['title']=array(
    '#description'=>t('Enter title.'),
    '#type'=>'textfield',
    '#size'=>50,
    '#default_value'=>'default',
);
$form['submit']=array(
        '#type'=>'submit',
        '#value'=>'Submit',
);
    $form['clear']=array(
        '#type'=>'submit',
        '#value'=>'Reset form',
        '#validate'=>array('mymodule_myform_clear') //redirects to the _clear function defined below
);
    return $form;
}
    function mymodule_myform_clear($form, $form_state) {
        unset($form_state['values']);
        $form_state['rebuild']=TRUE; //clears the form
    }

    function mymodule_myform_submit($form, &$form_state) {
        $values=$form_state['values'];
        die('the value you submitted: '.$values['title']);
```

Both functions get called when the Reset from button is pressed. Why is the `#validate` property not doing its job?

Comment: Try unsetting `$form_state['input']` as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Clive said resetting `$form_state['input']` is the solution, however I'd rather handle both actions in the submit function:

```
function mymodule_myform_submit($form, &$form_state) {

  if($form_state['clicked_button']['#value'] == $form['clear']['#value']) {
    $form_state['input'] = array();
    $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
  } else {
    $values = $form_state['values'];
    die('the value you submitted: '.$values['title']);
  }

}
```

Comment: This is what I would do too: A validation handler should just validate the input, not resetting the values submitted by the users.

Comment: Thank you, this now prevents both functions from being called. Will give `#validate` up for the purpose I was trying to implement. Note that the idea came from [here](https://drupal.org/node/717742)